# Logging the request in case of an internal server error in JAX-RS application

Tags: jax-rs, quarkus

Whenever my rest application throws an internal error, I want to log the exact request that made it fail. To do that, I created a ContainerResponseFilter. It checks if the response status is greater than or equal to 500. If it is, it serialises the ContainerRequestContext and persist it on S3.

```
@Provider
@ApplicationScoped
public class GlobalContainerResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {
    @Override
    public void filter (ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) {
        if (responseContext.getStatus() >= 500) {
            ContainerRequestContextSerialiser serialiser = new ContainerRequestContextSerialiser();
            // creates a JSON with the URI, headers, form parameters, body of the request, and all the information available on ContainerRequestContext
            String json = serialiser.serialise(requestContext);
            AwsS3Client client = new AwsS3Client();
            client.persist(json, LocalDateTime.now());
        }
    }
}
```

I am having a hard time dealing with the entity input stream. If it was not read yet, I don't need to serialise it, because it was not the cause of the exception. Maybe the application failed to parse a query parameter, for example. If it was read, I want to serialise it, but I can't, because the stream can't be read again.
My first idea was to create a ContainerRequestFilter, like this:

```
@Provider
@ApplicationScoped
public class GlobalContainerRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter (ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
        requestContext.setEntityStream(new InputStreamThatCanBeReadAgain(requestContext.getEntityStream()));        
    }

    public static class InputStreamThatCanBeReadAgain extends InputStream {

        private final InputStream source;
        private final ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        public InputStreamThatCanBeReadAgain (InputStream source) {
            this.source = source;
        }

        @Override
        public int read () throws IOException {
            int read = source.read();
            os.write(read);
            return read;
        }

        public InputStream getInputStreamToBeReadAgain () {
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray());
        }
    }
}
```

Then, on ContainerResponseFilter, I would cast the entity stream to InputStreamThatCanBeReadAgain and get the data I need. But this is duplicating the entity information in memory for every request, even the ones that won't generate an internal error, which is supposed to be the vast majority of them.

So, is there another way to get this done? I suppose the entity information is already present somewhere, and I just need to get its bytes.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to all container and client requests in my Quarkus application using the code below.

```
package br.com.mobiauto.bankflow.jaxrs;

import br.com.mobiauto.bankflow.Resources;
import br.com.mobiauto.bankflow.model.entity.state.IntegrationLog;
import br.com.mobiauto.bankflow.repository.abstraction.state.IntegrationLogRepository;
import br.com.mobiauto.lib.jackson.WriterType;
import br.com.mobiauto.lib.utils.DateUtils;
import br.com.mobiauto.lib.utils.JavaUtils;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter;
import org.jboss.logging.Logger;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientResponseContext;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientResponseFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URI;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Provider
@ApplicationScoped
public class IntegrationLogFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter, ClientResponseFilter {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(IntegrationLogFilter.class);

    @WriterType
    @Inject ObjectWriter objectWriter;
    @Inject IntegrationLogRepository repository;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext request) throws IOException {
        if (containerRequestShouldBeLogged(request) && containerRequestHasSupportedEntity(request)) {
            request.setEntityStream(new MyLoggingStream(request.getEntityStream()));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext request, ContainerResponseContext response) throws IOException {
        if (containerRequestShouldBeLogged(request)) {
            try {
                IntegrationLog log = new IntegrationLog();
                log.setDateTime(DateUtils.nowInBrazil().toLocalDateTime());
                log.setRequestHeaders(toString(request.getHeaders()));
                log.setRequestMethod(request.getMethod());
                if (containerRequestHasSupportedEntity(request)) {
                    log.setRequestBodyJson(((MyLoggingStream) request.getEntityStream()).getString());
                }
                log.setRequestUrl(getRequestUrl(request.getUriInfo()));
                log.setResponseHeaders(toString(response.getStringHeaders()));
                if (containerResponseHasSupportedEntity(response)) {
                    log.setResponseBodyJson(objectWriter.writeValueAsString(response.getEntity()));
                }
                persist(log);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Could not log the container request!", e);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void filter(ClientRequestContext request, ClientResponseContext response) throws IOException {
        try {
            IntegrationLog log = new IntegrationLog();
            log.setDateTime(DateUtils.nowInBrazil().toLocalDateTime());
            log.setRequestHeaders(toString(request.getStringHeaders()));
            log.setRequestMethod(request.getMethod());
            if (clientRequestHasSupportedEntity(request)) {
                log.setRequestBodyJson(objectWriter.writeValueAsString(request.getEntity()));
            }
            log.setRequestUrl(getRequestUrl(request.getUri()));
            log.setResponseHeaders(toString(response.getHeaders()));
            if (clientResponseHasSupportedEntity(response)) {
                String responseJson = JavaUtils.toString(response.getEntityStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
                log.setResponseBodyJson(responseJson);
                response.setEntityStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(responseJson.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
            }
            persist(log);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Could not log the client request!", e);
        }
    }

    @Transactional
    public void persist(IntegrationLog entity) {
        repository.persist(entity);
    }

    private String getRequestUrl(URI uri) {
        return uri.toString().replace(Resources.INTEGRATIONS, "");
    }

    private String getRequestUrl(UriInfo uriInfo) {
        String baseUri = uriInfo.getBaseUri().toString();
        String requestUri = uriInfo.getRequestUri().toString();
        return requestUri.replace(baseUri, "").replace(Resources.INTEGRATIONS, "");
    }

    private boolean clientRequestHasSupportedEntity(ClientRequestContext request) {
        return request.hasEntity() && request.getMediaType().equals(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
    }

    private boolean containerRequestHasSupportedEntity(ContainerRequestContext request) {
        return request.hasEntity() && request.getMediaType().equals(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
    }

    private boolean clientResponseHasSupportedEntity(ClientResponseContext response) {
        return response.hasEntity() && response.getMediaType().equals(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
    }

    private boolean containerResponseHasSupportedEntity(ContainerResponseContext response) {
        return response.hasEntity() && response.getMediaType().equals(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
    }

    private boolean containerRequestShouldBeLogged(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext) {
        UriInfo uriInfo = containerRequestContext.getUriInfo();
        String requestUri = uriInfo.getRequestUri().toString();
        return requestUri.contains(Resources.INTEGRATIONS);
    }

    private String toString(MultivaluedMap<String, String> map) {
        return map.
                entrySet().
                stream().
                map(entry -> entry.getKey() + ":" + String.join(",", entry.getValue())).
                collect(Collectors.joining(";"));
    }

    private static class MyLoggingStream extends InputStream {

        private final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        private final InputStream inputStream;

        public MyLoggingStream(final InputStream inputStream) {
            this.inputStream = inputStream;
        }

        public String getString() {
            return baos.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        }

        @Override
        public int read() throws IOException {
            int read = inputStream.read();
            if (read > -1) {
                baos.write(read);
            }
            return read;
        }
    }
}
```